# Convert element in string array to character

Tags: java, arrays, type-conversion

given an array             `String [] stringtest= new String[]{"dog","bark","1","m"};`

how could I store the fourth element as a character? The reason being that I need to compare the last element to a character inside an if statement.

I need  `if(stringtest[3]=='m')` to work

Comment: Why can you not do `if(stringtest[3].equals("m"))`?

Comment: Can you elaborate why you need to compare a string to a character?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you can convert string to char array

```
char[] ch= stringtest[3].toCharArray();
if(ch[0]=='m')
```

or you can use charAt method

```
if(stringtest[3].charAt(0)=='m')
```

Answer (score 1):

you can use `toCharArray()` method of string

this would work, although not clear why you want it like that

```
if( stringtest[3].toCharArray()[0] == 'm')
```